# Importing multiple files from Google Cloud Bucket to Datalab instance

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-datalab

I have a bucket set up on Google Cloud containing a few hundred json files and am trying to work with them in a datalab instance running python 3.

So, I can easily see them as objects using

```
gcs list --objects gs://<BUCKET_NAME>
```

Further, I can read in an individual file/object using

```
 import google.datalab.storage as storage
 import pandas as pd
 from io import BytesIO

 myBucket = storage.Bucket('<BUCKET_NAME')
 data_csv = myBucket.object('<FILE_NAME.json')

 uri = data_csv.uri
 %gcs read --object $uri --variable data

 df = pd.read_csv(BytesIO(data))
 df.head()
```

(FYI, I understand that my example is reading a json as a csv, but let's ignore that- I'll cross that bridge on my own)

What I can't figure out is how to loop through the bucket and pull all of the json files into pandas...how do I do that? Is that the way I should be thinking of this- is there a way to call the files in the bucket from pandas directly (since they're already treated as objects)?

As an extra bit- what if a file is saved as a json, but isn't actually that structure? How can I handle that?

Essentially, I guess, I'm looking for the functionality of the blob package, but using cloud buckets + datalab.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using [`Bucket.objects`](https://googledatalab.github.io/pydatalab/google.datalab.storage.html#google.datalab.storage.Bucket.objects) which returns an iterator with all matching files. Specify a prefix or leave it empty to match all files in the bucket. I did an example with two files `countries1.csv` and `countries2.csv`:

```
$ cat countries1.csv
id,country
1,sweden
2,spain

$ cat countries2.csv
id,country
3,italy
4,france
```

And used the following Datalab snippet:

```
import google.datalab.storage as storage
import pandas as pd
from io import BytesIO

myBucket = storage.Bucket('BUCKET_NAME')
object_list = myBucket.objects(prefix='countries')

df_list = []

for object in object_list:
  %gcs read --object $object.uri --variable data  
  df_list.append(pd.read_csv(BytesIO(data)))

concatenated_df = pd.concat(df_list, ignore_index=True)
concatenated_df.head()
```

which will output the combined csv:

```
    id  country
0   1   sweden
1   2   spain
2   3   italy
3   4   france
```

Take into account that I combined all csv files into a single Pandas dataframe using [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20906474/import-multiple-csv-files-into-pandas-and-concatenate-into-one-dataframe) but you might want to load them into different ones depending on the use case. If you want to retrieve all files in the bucket just use this instead:

```
object_list = myBucket.objects()
```